# Слайдер с возможностью вставки видео

Tags: jquery

Нужен простой слайдер с возможностью вставки видео. Подскажите нормальный, пожалуйста

Comment: вставка видео _в слайдер_? ваш заказчик знает толк в извращениях.

Comment: Согласен, что Ваш заказчик с творчеством подошел к вопросу (-:

Слайдеров огромное множество вот тут посмотрите, надеюсь найдёте по своим запросам [смотреть][1]

  


А для проигрывания видео попробуйте jPlayer вот [статья][2]


  [1]: http://ruseller.com/search.php?s=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80
  [2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/112776/

Comment: Советую делать так: есть некая статическая картинка - при её нажатии активировать плеер, иначе галактические тормоза обеспечены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот посмотрите этот слайдер [здесь](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-5) он со вставленным видео с youtube.com

Надеюсь будет полезна эта ссылка.